# Difference between two dates in excel 2013

Tags: excel, formulas

I want to calculate the time difference between two dates with the following criteria:

1) excluding sundays and public holidays

2) TIMING:  Mon to Fri  = 7 AM to 7 PM & 
            Sat         = 7 AM to 3 PM

I tried a many formulas and nothing works for me.
please any ideas??

Eg: Start Time: 3/6/2015 10:00 AM

End Time: 4/6/2015 12:00 PM

Then I should get the difference as 13 hrs (excluding time out of business hours)

Comment: Please provide some example date/times, and the results that you are expecting. You might get some help then.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: Will the start and end timestamps always be within working hours? It's a less complex calculation if that's the case

Comment: @barry houdini: yes, it will be within working hours

Comment: i dont know why i dont get the normal hour calculation also in a right way. For Eg: A1= 3//5/2015 10 AM B1= 4/5/2015 10 AM( custom format- d/mm/yyyy h:mm) c1=B2-A1(custom format h:mm)  The answer should be  for this example 24 hrs. i dont get answer for this too.. i dont know where i am going wrong...!!

Comment: That's simply a formatting issue - h:mm only shows "clock time", I.e. No higher than 23:59. For "elapsed time" use custom format [h]:mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **start and end "timestamps" will always be within working hours** then you can use a formula like this:

`=(SUM(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,{1,"1111101"},H$2:H$10)*{12,8})-IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=7,8,12))/24+MOD(B2,1)-MOD(A2,1)`

Assuming start date/time in `A2`, end date/time in `B2` and holiday list in `H2:H10`

Format result cell as `[h]:mm` and if start time is today (Monday) at 14:00 and end time is exactly a week later you will get the result **68:00** (5*12 hour days and 1*8 hour Saturday)

Comment: :a2= 8/5/2015 10:00 b2 = 9/5/2015 16:00 gives
c2= 18:00 , but saturday timing from 7am to 3 pm. b2 date is saturday, the answe should be 17:00 hrs right? can u give further ideas?? thanks in advance

Comment: ....but that was why I asked about working hours - 9/5/2015 16:00 isn't witjhin the working hours, is that a valid finish time, after the finish of working hours at 15:00?

Comment: yes.. u r rite. but i just thought whether it will minus the timing which don't come under working hours.I will find some other way. thanks for the great help..